# SQL date format bind variable

Tags: date, variables, format, bind

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this SQL query.

```
select 
    USERNAME, DATECREATED, CREDTYPE, USAGETYPE,  OPERATIONID, TXNID, CALLERID 
from 
    arwfissuanceauditlog 
where 
    OPERATIONID in (2104,2107) 
and datecreated >= 'to_date('2010/06/21', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')' 
and datecreated < 'to_date('2010/08/03', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')'
```

I got this message when I ran it in SQL developer

```
Unknown Command
Bind Variable "MI" is NOT DECLARED
```

I am calling this from java like this

```
try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            results = stmt.executeQuery(queryToExecute);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            CredChangeReportSVC.DEFAULTLOGGER.error("An exception occurred while executing query: " + queryToExecute, e);
}
```

In the logs I get this message

```
ERROR 03 Aug 2010 14:51:06,939 - An exception occurred while executing query: "select USERNAME, DATECREATED, CREDTYPE, USAGETYPE,  OPERATIONID, TXNID, CALLERID from arwfissuanceauditlog where OPERATIONID in (2104,2107) and datecreated >= 'to_date('2010/06/21', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')' and datecreated < 'to_date('2010/08/03', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')'"
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL type
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format specifies a time part, but you have omitted this in your datetime strings. Drop the "HH24:MI:SS" from the date strings and try again